# react router dom don't work to access some component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Good morning community StackOverflow.I had to use the route to access some component inside the application but that's not work for me despite I had installed the "npm install react-router-dom" the browser render me a blank file,so this is all my file :
app.js file :

```
import React from 'react';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import ProductScreen from './screens/ProductScreen';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
     
   <div className="grid-container" >
    <header className="row" >
      <div>
        <a className="brand" href="/">My Shop</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="/cart">Cart</a>
        <a href="/signin">Sign In</a>
      </div>
    </header >
    <main>
   
   <Route path="/" component={HomeScreen} ></Route>
   <Route path="/product/:id" component={ProductScreen} ></Route>
      
    </main>
    <footer classNameName="row center" >All right reserved</footer>
   </div>
  
   </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

this is the HomeScreen file :

```
import React from "react";
import {data} from '../data';
import Product from '../components/Product';

function HomeScreen () {
    return (
        <div>
        <div className="row center">
      {data.products.map((product) => (
       <Product key={product._id} product={product} ></Product> 
        ))}
     
  </div>
  </div>
    )
};
export default HomeScreen;
```

this is the ProductScreen file :

```
import React from "react";

function ProductScreen () {
    return (
        <div>Product Screen</div>
    )
};
export default ProductScreen;
```

this is the Product file code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Rating from './Rating';

function Product (props) {
    const {product} = props;
    return (

         <div className="card">
          <a href="product.html">
            <img className="medium" src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
          </a>
          <div className="card-body">
            <a href="product.html">
            <h2>{product.name}</h2>  
            </a>
           <Rating rating={product.rating} numReviews={product.numReviews} ></Rating>
            <div className="price" >${product.price}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Product;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In react router v6, lots of keywords have changed. In addition, various functions like useHistory have also been changed. Check the package version in `package.json` file. You can also check your browser console for errors.

In case you have v6 or above, change your `app.js` as below, to make it work. I have changed the react router keywords, indented code and made `Route` tag as self closing.

```
import React from 'react';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import ProductScreen from './screens/ProductScreen';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="grid-container" >
        <header className="row" >
          <div>
            <a className="brand" href="/">My Shop</a>
          </div>
          <div>
            <a href="/cart">Cart</a>
            <a href="/signin">Sign In</a>
          </div>
        </header>
      <main>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} />
          <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductScreen />} />
        </Routes>
      </main>
      <footer classNameName="row center" >All right reserved</footer>
     </div>
   </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: thank you for your attention my friend but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Have you checked package.json for react router version & what errors are you getting in browser console when navigating?

Comment: this is the version inside the package.json file : { "name": "frontend", "version": "0.1.0", "private": true, "dependencies": { "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2", "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3", "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0", "react": "^17.0.2", "react-dom": "^17.0.2", "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1", "react-scripts": "^3.0.1", "web-vitals": "^2.1.4" }

Comment: the issue in the inspect is: Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform

Comment: this is the exact error in console:
react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:117 Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend it work now with Routes

Comment: Happy to help. Looks like you were not importing your screens properly as well apart from using older keywords that have been removed.

Comment: i had mark it.you don' see it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using version 6, you have to wrap `<Route>` components with `<Routes>` (you should import the component first), otherwise, wrap them with `<Switch>` component

Comment: sorry, my friend i try it but it don't work

Comment: this is the version inside the package.json file : {
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  }

Comment: the issue in the inspect is: Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform

Comment: so you're using version 6. Make sure you first wrap `<Route>` with `<Routes>` .... Change `component` prop to `element` and add the angle brackets when you specify the pages. Check this link for more info [Upgrade to React Router v6](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#upgrade-to-react-router-v6)